Non Canonical Splicing and Alternative Splicing
I am struggling to understand concept of non-canonical splicing. I couldn't find satisfying answer to how non-canonical splicing work, what are the mechanism of it, how does it distinguish from canonical splicing? or is alternative splicing the same term for non-canonical splicing?

Can you post an example of how people are using the term that you find confusing? Different people might use it in different ways. Is this from a textbook? It would be helpful to get a link or some kind of citation. For example, this paper discusses it in detail. Is there something that you find confusing there?

Here's a recent review by Consuelo Pitolli  (I'm not specifically recommending it - it's just a recent relevant hit from PubMed, very readable)  Non-canonical splicing breaks rules, so you can do interesting things: make circular RNAs, do trans-splicing ("RNA-viral sex"), etc.  Alternate splicing just means there is some way to change what splice product is made.  Sorry I don't have time at the moment  to make a full answer.
